Browser extension to save a ChatGPT conversation as Markdown
For education purposes, I need to keep track of ChatGPT conversations, so I want to save them as markdown files.

It should integrate into the browser, either Firefox, Chrome or Opera.
It saves a single chat as a single Markdown file
It formats code as code with the correct language tag
It saves formulas as Markdown Inline Math (like $\LaTeX$)
It gets bullet points and enumerations right
It's free (gratis, open-source preferred)
optional: It includes information about the model I was using (like 4/4o/4o-mini/o1)
optional: It includes date and time information when I created the chat.

I have tried:

ChatGPT to markdown Firefox extension, but it doesn't save formulas well. Basically I get each formula 3 times: as text, as LateX and as Unicode. I just want Markdown Inline Math, no alternate representations (or an option to choose one representation). It also omits code blocks when I ask about coding.


Sometimes it helps to just use the prompt "Repeat the last response as raw markdown, (and add the current date and time,...)" I understand that this is infeasible for long back-and-forth conversations. But it helps to grab important responses as markdown blocks ready to cut-and-paste.
